# Having the user draw a box around a portion of an image

Tags: javascript, image, annotations

I'm not fluent in more than basic javascript, but I am looking to have a way that the user can draw a box around a certain portion of image, and then have the coordinates accessible so I can save them. Something similar to tagging photos in Facebook. Does anybody know of any libraries I can reuse? Any tips to get started?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery image crop plugin.](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) It's the most usable and beautiful plugin for the requirement that I know.

[Here](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php) are some examples. You should be able to fetch the coordinates as shown in the [event handler demo.](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler)

Comment: This is great! Just the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks so much.